# Retrieve data from API call response?

Tags: c#, rest

I'm working on an application to get some API experience with C#. I'm pulling data from a site involving jokes, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the actual response.

I've gone over several different methods, this is the farthest I've gotten. I'm using the RestSharp library, and it's returning RestSharp.RestResponse. I've tried several different methods of deserializing this as that's what I believe is needed. From the API I'm using, the default response format is text/html. Any tips on extracting this to a string containing the joke itself would be most appreciated.

```
    public void CreateJoke()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
        client.AddDefaultHeader("user-agent", "Dadbot");

        var request = new RestRequest("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
        var response = client.Get(request);
        lblJoke.Text = response.ToString();
    }
```

Expected result: getting a string I can put into a label. Actual result: RestSharp.RestResponse.

Comment: This is because you're getting a ```RestResponse``` back not a string like you're thinking.  I think what you're looking for is ```lblJoke.Text = response.Data.ToString()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```
public string CreateJoke()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "text/plain";

    var jokeResponse = request.GetResponse();

    var joke = string.Empty;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(jokeResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       joke = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(joke);

    return joke;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try instead accessing the `Content` property of `response`:

```
public void CreateJoke()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
    client.AddDefaultHeader("user-agent", "Dadbot");

    var request = new RestRequest("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
    var response = client.Get(request);
    lblJoke.Text = response.Content;
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is the answer but it appears ```Content``` is a ```string``` which makes ```ToString()``` redundant.  If this is indeed the correct link... https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/42f086a895ae3cb8c295557086eba0d3fb1df22c/RestSharp/RestResponse.cs

Comment: That's great! That helps me get the response, which has 3 properties. From those 3 properties, I only need one. But that should be much easier to do I think? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the structure of your response string, for example if it’s stringified JSON, you could convert that to an object pretty easily with a library such as JsonConvert and extract some specific property.